# Как сделать оформление заказа WooCommerce и wp через Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Говоря другими словами мне нужно чтобы форма понимала, что у меня сейчас в корзине есть и отправляла это вместе с ФИО тд в вукомерс. Все сейчас реализовано на Contact Form 7 и купить в один клик, форма знает какой товар я хочу купить, но когда доходите в корзину она отправляет ток ФИО в укомерс, без товара и количества и тд, а ответьте как это реализовать, целый день голову ломаю